Clarification on the forward extended Euclidean algorithm for finding gcd and linear solution
I have been reviewing Bill Dubuque's explanation of a forward version of the extended Euclidean algorithm in another question. I have seen other explanations of this method on the internet, but Bill's explanation was the only one that gave a logical reason for the addition of extra variables, i.e., using matrix operations to keep "track of each remainder's expression as a linear combination of the gcd arguments."
Here is my question: Bill stops the process when the remainder is 1 or -1. Usually in the Euclidean algorithm, we don't stop until the remainder is zero, so we know that the gcd is the remainder of previous step. Is it merely that, being $\pm 1$, the next step must have a remainder of 0?
I also find it easier to write out the problem of, say gcd(141,19) in this way:
$
\begin{align}
R1:& &1& &0& &|& &141& &141=& \; 7\cdot 19+8& \;\;\;\;\;\; R1-7R2 &\to R3& \\
R2:& &0& &1& &|& &19&  &19=& \; 2\cdot 8+3& \;\;\;\;\;\; R2-2R3 &\to R4& \\
R3:& &1& &-7& &|& &8&  &8=& \; 2\cdot 3+2& \;\;\;\;\;\; R3-2R4 &\to R5& \\
R4:& &-2& &15& &|& &3& &3=& \; 1\cdot 2+1& \;\;\;\;\;\; R4-R5 &\to R6& \\
R5:& &5& &-37& &|& &2& &2=& \; 2\cdot 1+0& \;\;\;\;\;\; R5-2R6 &\to R7& \\ 
R6:& &-7& &52& &|& &1& \\ 
R7:& &19& &-141& &|& &0& 
\end{align}
$
So that the gcd(141, 19) = 1, and the linear combination of 141 and 19 to equal 1 is:  $-7\cdot 141+52\cdot 19=1$.
Because I am still learning these methods, I prefer not to skip any steps. Otherwise, I think I understand the method.

This is the main all my posts link to, and it does include all the steps.  Further it displays the calculation in (Hermite) row reduction form, which here is
$$\left[ \begin{array}{r} -7 & 52\ 19 &!! -141\end{array}\right ]
\left[ \begin{array}{r} 141 & 1 & 0\ 19 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right ]
\ =\  \left[ \begin{array}{r} \color{#c00}1\ &  \color{#c00}{-7}\ & \color{#c00}{52}\ \color{#0a0}0\ & \color{#0a0}{19}\ &!!! \color{#0a0}{-141}\end{array}\right]
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

$\begin{align}\text{Notice row 1 is the $\ \ $ particular $\ \ $  solution }\ &\color{#c00}{1 =\    {-}7(141) ,+,52(19)}\
\text{Notice row 2 is the homogeneous solution }\ &\color{#0a0}{0 =,\ 19(141) -141(19)}
\end{align}\ \ $

Generally we can stop when some remainder $,r_n,$ divides the prior $,r_{n-1},,$ say $,\color{#0af}{r_{n-1} = kr_n},,$ since then $,(r_1,r_2) = (\color{#0af}{r_{n-1}},r_n) = \color{#0af}{r_n}(\color{#0af}{k},1)=r_n,,$ and the final equation yields the Bezout identity $,\color{#c00}{r_n = a r_1 + b r_2} =,$ first row above. Usually we don't need the second $\rm\color{#0a0}{green}$ row corresponding to a final remainder $,r_{n+1}  =\color{#0a0} 0.\ \ $

Note: I use the common notation $,(j,k) := \gcd(j,k),$ in the prior comment. $\ \ $

Here is how it looks if you write the continued fraction for your ratio....
Note how the convergents give little 2 by 2 crossed products that are always $\pm 1. $  The pair $\frac{7}{1}, \frac{15}{2}$  gives $7 \cdot 2 - 15 \cdot 1 = -1. $   Next pair $ \frac{15}{2}, \frac{37}{5}$  gives $15 \cdot 5 - 37 \cdot 2 = 1. $   Next pair $  \frac{37}{5}, \frac{52}{7}$  gives $37 \cdot 7 - 52 \cdot 5 = -1. $  Finally $  \frac{52}{7}, \frac{141}{19}$  gives $52 \cdot 19 - 141 \cdot 7 = 1. $
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$  \gcd( 141, 19 ) = ???    $$
$$ \frac{ 141 }{ 19 } = 7 +  \frac{ 8 }{ 19 } $$
$$ \frac{ 19 }{ 8 } = 2 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 } $$
$$ \frac{ 8 }{ 3 } = 2 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 } $$
$$ \frac{ 3 }{ 2 } = 1 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$
$$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 7 & & 2 & & 2 & & 1 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 15 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 37 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 52 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 141 }{ 19 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 141 \cdot 7 - 19 \cdot 52 = -1 $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Please don't keep duplicating your prior CF answers ad infinitum. Instead you could have posted a comment linking to one of your prior answers, e.g. here. Not to mention this is not an answer to the question.
